# how to remove the last item of gridview with onlick event in android

Tags: java, android, gridview, onclicklistener

my problem is to remove the last element in a gridview , this gridview has an adapter and is controlled by the content of their arraylist .

I saw that the problem lies in doing the click on a child element of the gridview , as removal element for directly setOnItemClickListener no problem.
This is my code:

```
//evento click para cada item del adaptador
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> m_parent, View o_view, int e_position, long e_id) {
        if(flag) {
            View view = o_view.findViewById(R.id.close_image);
            view.setTag(R.id.close_image, e_position);

            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int posicion = (int) v.getTag(R.id.close_image);
                    gridAdapter.removeAt(posicion);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The last element does not disappear or is not removed from the design, still exist in the arraylist .
Adapter:

```
public abstract class AdapterGridView extends ArrayAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList data = new ArrayList();

    public AdapterGridView(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int e_position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if( convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        }

        onEntrada(data.get(e_position), convertView);

        return convertView;
    }

    public boolean removeAt(int e_index) {
        Object o_out = data.remove(e_index);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return ( o_out != null );
    }

    public abstract void onEntrada(Object o_entrada, View o_view);
}
```

And design element gridview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:padding="5dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:src="@drawable/logo1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/close_image"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/image"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@id/image"
                android:src="@drawable/delete2"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

gridview properties

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/textFoot"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/head_directorio"/>
```

Comment: Shuldn't you do `Object o_out = data.removeAt(e_index);` instead of `Object o_out = data.remove(e_index);`?

Comment: Yes, this correct, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final code

```
public boolean removeAt(int e_index) {
        Object o_out = data.remove(e_index);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return ( o_out != null );
    }
```